# Transition from yahoo groups to google groups

Tags: yahoo-api, data-conversion, google-groups

A yahoo group I'm in is preparing for the possibility of yahoo's demise.

They are investigating the transition to google groups.

We do not want to give up either backlog or attribution of the 13,000 some posts.

Is there a way to transfer information, including users of individual posts from yahoo groups to google groups.

Alternately, is it possible from Yahoo groups to something like phpBB.

I am posting this in both Stack Exchange and in Google products forum.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/groups-migration/index

Answer (score 5):

While the question is an old one, others may be interested to know that using the Google Groups Migration API it is possible to upload the users and the data from Yahoo Groups.

Sequence:

1. Download your Yahoo Group data using Personal Groupware http://www.personalgroupware.com
2. Export the the data into your chosen database (e.g. MySql)
3. Upload the data using the Google Groups Migration API
   https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-migration/v1/get-start/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to transfer your group to Google.

The upload of group data follows this pattern:

1. Upload Users
2. Upload Subjects
3. Upload Replies

You will be stuck at 1) as you are unable to create the list of users on Google. You do not have write access to the Google user database.

For phpbb this will definitely be possible as you have full control of the database.